# LED matrix controller - Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I'm an ECE student. My experience in Verilog and FPGAs is mainly from my digital logic design class. To practice Verilog, I decided to implement a controller for Adafruit LED matrices. It interfaces with a single-port BRAM to access pixel data.

If helpful, here is an overview of how it works:

The design has an FSM that alternates between the `DISPLAY_1` and `DISPLAY_2` states to read pixel data and generate an address for the BRAM each clock cycle. In the `DISPLAY_2` state, it writes the pixel data to registers connected to the `o_color1` and `o_color2` output signals. Since this design drives the clock (`o_clk`) for the LED matrix, I ensure that these output signals only change on the falling edge of `o_clk`. After driving the data for all the pixels in a row, it increments the `o_row_sel` register to select the next two rows.

led_matrix_controller.v:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module led_matrix_controller 
  #(parameter MATRIX_COLS = 64,
    parameter MATRIX_ROWS = 32,
    parameter PWM_BITS = 1
  )
   (input i_clk,
    input rst,
    input [(3*PWM_BITS)-1:0] i_pixel_data,
    output reg [$clog2(MATRIX_COLS*MATRIX_ROWS)-1:0] o_pixel_addr,
    output reg o_clk,
    output reg o_oe,
    output reg o_latch,
    output reg [$clog2(MATRIX_ROWS/2)-1:0] o_row_sel,
    output [2:0] o_color1,
    output [2:0] o_color2
  );

    wire [$clog2(MATRIX_ROWS/2)-1:0] o_row_sel_next = o_row_sel + 1;

    reg [$clog2(MATRIX_COLS):0] pixel_counter;
    reg [PWM_BITS-1:0] pwm_counter;

    reg first_cycle;

    reg [(3*PWM_BITS)-1:0] pixel_1;
    reg [(3*PWM_BITS)-1:0] pixel_2;
    reg [(3*PWM_BITS)-1:0] temp_pixel;

    assign o_color1 = color(pixel_1);
    assign o_color2 = color(pixel_2);

    function [2:0] color (input reg [(3*PWM_BITS)-1:0] pixel);
        color = {
            (pwm_counter < pixel[PWM_BITS-1:0]),
            (pwm_counter < pixel[(2*PWM_BITS)-1:PWM_BITS]),
            (pwm_counter < pixel[(3*PWM_BITS)-1:2*PWM_BITS])
        };
    endfunction

    reg [2:0] state;

    localparam STATE_DISPLAY_1  = 3'b000;
    localparam STATE_DISPLAY_2  = 3'b001;
    localparam STATE_BLANK_1    = 3'b010;
    localparam STATE_BLANK_2    = 3'b011;
    localparam STATE_BLANK_3    = 3'b100;

    always @(posedge i_clk)
    begin
        if(rst)
            begin
                o_clk         <= 0;
                o_oe          <= 0;
                o_latch       <= 0;
                o_row_sel     <= ~0;
                o_pixel_addr  <= 0;
                
                pixel_1       <= 0;
                pixel_2       <= 0;
                temp_pixel    <= 0;
                
                pixel_counter <= 0;
                pwm_counter   <= 0;
                first_cycle   <= 1;
                
                state <= STATE_DISPLAY_2;
            end
        else
            begin
                case(state)
                    STATE_DISPLAY_1:
                    begin
                        o_oe <= 0;
                        o_latch <= 0;
                        o_clk <= !first_cycle;

                        temp_pixel <= i_pixel_data;

                        if(pixel_counter > MATRIX_COLS)
                        begin
                            state <= STATE_BLANK_1;
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                            o_pixel_addr <= pixel_counter + MATRIX_COLS*o_row_sel_next;
                            state <= STATE_DISPLAY_2;
                        end
                    end
                    STATE_DISPLAY_2:
                    begin
                        o_clk <= 0;
                        first_cycle <= 0;

                        if(!first_cycle)
                        begin
                            pixel_1 <= temp_pixel;
                            pixel_2 <= i_pixel_data;
                        end

                        o_pixel_addr <= pixel_counter + MATRIX_COLS*(MATRIX_ROWS/2 + o_row_sel_next);
                        pixel_counter <= pixel_counter + 1;

                        state <= STATE_DISPLAY_1;
                    end
                    STATE_BLANK_1:
                    begin
                        if(o_pixel_addr != 0)
                        begin
                            pixel_1 <= temp_pixel;
                            pixel_2 <= i_pixel_data;
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                            pixel_1 <= i_pixel_data;
                            pixel_2 <= temp_pixel;
                        end

                        o_clk <= 0;
                        pixel_counter[$clog2(MATRIX_COLS)] = 0;
                        state <= STATE_BLANK_2;
                    end
                    STATE_BLANK_2:
                    begin
                        o_oe <= 1;
                        state <= STATE_BLANK_3;
                    end
                    STATE_BLANK_3:
                    begin
                        o_row_sel <= o_row_sel + 1;
                        o_latch <= 1;
                        first_cycle <= 1;

                        if(o_row_sel == (MATRIX_ROWS/2)-2)
                        begin
                            pwm_counter <= pwm_counter + 1;
                        end

                        state <= STATE_DISPLAY_1;
                    end
                endcase
            end
    end
endmodule
```

single_port_ram_sync.v:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Single-port RAM With Synchronous Read (Read Through)
// Modified from XST v-rams-07
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module single_port_ram_sync
  #(parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 6,
    parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8,
    parameter INIT_FILE = ""
  )
   (input clk, 
    input we,
    input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] addr,
    input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] din,
    output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] dout
  );
    
    reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] ram [2**ADDR_WIDTH-1:0];
    reg [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] r_addr;
    
    initial
    begin
        $readmemh(INIT_FILE, ram);
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (we)
        begin
            ram[addr] <= din;
        end
        r_addr <= addr;
    end
    
    assign dout = ram[r_addr];
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

The code follows recommended practices regarding the use of nonblocking assignments, consistent indentation and parameter usage.

One exception is the line:

```
                    pixel_counter[$clog2(MATRIX_COLS)] = 0;
```

That should use a nonblocking assignment:

```
                    pixel_counter[$clog2(MATRIX_COLS)] <= 0;
```

The state machine in the `led_matrix_controller` module has a 3-bit state register.  This means that there are 8 possible values for the register (0-7).  Since you only require 5 defined states (0-4), this leaves 3 unassigned states (5-7).  Although you can not reach the unassigned states in a normal Verilog simulation, in silicon it may be possible if you encounter a [soft error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error).  It is a common practice to guard against this type of error by accounting for all possible states using a `default` clause in your `case` statement. For example:

```
                default:
                begin
                    state <= STATE_DISPLAY_2;
                end
            endcase
```

The `~0` syntax is legal, and it does what you want, but I don't think it is all that common or easy to understand.  It would be better to use the `'1` syntax, which does require you to enable SystemVerilog features in your tools (most tools support SV these days).  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.7.1 *Integer literal constants*.  The code would then be:

```
            o_row_sel     <= '1;
```

Another common approach is to use the replicated concatenation operator to explicitly declare the signal width:

```
            o_row_sel     <= {ROWSEL_WIDTH{1'b1}};
```

where you would create a parameter named `ROWSEL_WIDTH`, for example.